# iframe fancybox responsive

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I'd like for my popin to respond in a responsive way horizontally, but not vertically.
When I use fancybox in order to call img it works, but not when it's for iframe.

[Check the difference between my first work and the second.](http://freymathias.com)

I use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fancybox').fancybox({
   openEffect: 'elastic',
   closeEffect: 'elastic',
   prevEffect: 'fade',
   nextEffect: 'fade',
   fitToView: true, // 
   maxWidth: "90%", // 
   type: 'iframe',
   scrolling: 'no',
   iframe : {
    scrolling : 'no'
   }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may actually need to set `fitToView` to `false` instead.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false, // <-- so it will take your values into account
    // other API options etc.
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uz85v/)**

Comment: Thanks, it works.

That's what I did, and now I understand why I was wrong...

With "www" before my domain name, it works. Without "www", it doesn't works; I don't understand why there is a difference.

Comment: @user3435194 : You may not be able to access your site without `www` because you may have a redirection rule in your `.htaccess` file that blocks entries without `www`, but it's a guess.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I wrote the links to the iframe like that : `http://www.freymathias.com/file/test.html`.
With `http://freymathias.com/file/test.htm`l or `/file.test.html` the problem is solved.
I'll still make a URL redirection. Thank you for your speed and your skills JFK.